# Including Concatenated Typescript JS outFile - Angular 2 + Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I've got the following code:

*index.html*

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

<script src="test.js"></script

<script>

  System.import('test.js')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outFile": "test.js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

And in the root of my project I have the "outFile" created by tsc named as "test.js" - it appears that all of the components, modules, etc are concatenated in test.js correctly but the app doesn't load anything other than the initial "loading..." and there are no console errors when visiting index.html in the browser.'

Also note that the initial index.html:

```
<body>
  <rz-app>Loading...</rz-app>
</body>
```

So I actually just get "loading..." on the html page.

I've been beating my head against a wall and I know it is something simple...

**Q** So, what am I doing wrong - how do I include the concatenated ts outFile in my html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this has been figured out yet, but I was running into the same issue and found this fixed it:

Look at your `test.js` file (the one that was outputted via tsc->outFile) and look for your app (looks like it's something like `rzApp`). There should be some code that looks something like `System.register("app", ["angular2/platform/browser", ...` The name (in this case `app`) is what you want to use in your `System.import()` call. So in my case, I used `System.import('app').then(null, console.error.bind(console));` and everything started working. Make sure you have your `test.js` in `<script>` tags.

I think this is similar to what was being described in the first answer, but it was unclear to me so I figured I'd re-word it in a way that helped me realize what was going on.

Comment: You just saved me hours. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

When specifying the `outFile` option within the tsc compiler, you need to include the corresponding file (`test.js`) in your case this way:

```
<script src="test.js"></script>

<script>
  System.import('boot')
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

You need to specify here the name of the module that contains the `bootstrap` processing. If the corresponding file is boot.ts, the module will be `boot`: `System.import('boot')`.

Note that in this case, the name of modules is specified within the `test.js` file within `System.register`:

```
System.register("boot", // <-------------
  ['angular2/platform/browser', 'angular2/http', "app.component", "app.service"], function(exports_5, context_5) {
  "use strict";
  (...)
});
```

Comment: Okay, it still is loading a blank app and no errors. In my dev tools I can see that the source file is indeed being returned with all of the JS inside. Any other ideas?

Comment: You could try to move the `<script>` block containing the import at this end of the `body` block of your HTML page...

Comment: Moreover you need to import the module containing the bootstrap processing. If it's in a file called `bootstrap.ts`, you need to use this: `System.import('boostrap');`. Now the name of modules are specified in the `test.js` file for each `System.register`.

Comment: I'm not exactly understanding your last comment. Could you provide a code example, please? Perhaps update your answer since it isn't the solution.

Comment: Could you also include a link referencing the documentation for this, please?

Comment: Here is the documentation for tsc configuration options: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html. I dug to find out how it works. So I'm not that there is documentation on this ;-)

Comment: No I have not yet. I'm not sure what the whole register block is all about. Where are those modules coming from like "angular2/platform/browser", etc.?

Comment: They are registered the same way within the `angular2.js` (or `angular2.dev.js` / `angular2.min.js`). If you have a look in it, we will see the `System.register('angular2/platform/browser', ...`.

Comment: In short I think that your problem is the string you provide to the initial `System.import` (not the js file name but the module containing the call to bootstrap rather) and eventually where you call it (could be moved at the end of the body block instead).

Comment: Still can't do it :( Would you by chance be able to do a hello world example from start to finish using NG2, Typescript, & SystemJS? I can get the app running but when I try to move files and concat/minify I run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

In case the solutions posted here did not help you, the following did the trick for me. It is partially based on a combination of @Thierry Templier's and @batesiic's answers as well as the answers described in [this systemjs issue](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1174). I am not exactly sure why it works, but it seems it is because the app package's format is described as 'register' and the app's map is the full path of the bundled JS file. This is my script block of my index.html:

```
<script src="/dist/bundledApp.js"></script> <!-- Needs to be here -->
<script>
    System.config({
        map: {
            app: 'dist/bundledApp.js', // <-- full path to bundled JS

            // other mappings...
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register', // <!-- this and the map.app value did the trick
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },

            // other packages...
        }
    });
    System.import('main') // <-- the name of the main.ts file containing the 
                          //     bootstrapping logic and is bundled in the
                          //     bundledApp.js file as System.register("main", ["@angula...
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

The `System.import('main')` points to the registered module that is defined in the bundled JS after it was compiled from my /src/main.ts file. This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "outFile": "./dist/bundledApp.js",
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./src/*.ts",
        "./src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true // for VS2015
}
```