# Angular2 TypeScript bundling

Tags: angular, systemjs, typescript1.8

I'm following instructions here: [A simple way to bundle an Angular 2 application](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-run-angular-2-in-production-today/) and in this SO question: [Including Concatenated Typescript JS outFile - Angular 2 + Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483746/including-concatenated-typescript-js-outfile-angular-2-typescript)

I set up my tsconfig.json as follows:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "system",
    //"outDir": "../wwwroot/",
    "outFile": "../wwwroot/dist/app.js",
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false
},
"exclude": [
    "../node_modules",
    "../wwwroot"
]
}
```

This compiles seemingly without issues and produces `dist/app.js` as expected. Inside the file, I can see the line that begins with `System.register("main", ...` so module `main` should be registered.

My index.html has this:

```
<script src="dist/app.js"></script>
System.import('main')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

I can see that `app.js` is being loaded by the browser, however all I get are 404 errors and exceptions from ZoneJS (`Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:5000/main.js`) attempting to load "main.js".

If I don't do this

```
System.import('main')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

then there are no errors, but the application does not start.

Any ideas what to do from here?

Comment: This is most likely not related to your `tsconfig.json` but rather your SystemJS configuration.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867660/build-angular2-html-and-typescript-to-a-single-file/35868706#35868706